# Unable to create log folder inside Wildfly server bin folder from docker container

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, wildfly

I am running a Java application inside  wildfly docker container. While starting the server, we create application log4j folders inside bin folder of wildfly (/opt/wildfly/bin).

I am getting exception:  Unable to create file `AppLog/AppLog.log java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /AppLog`

Command to run docker container: `docker run --name app_container --env-file=env-file -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -it app-resources /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh`

Comment: Aren't you missing write/execute rights to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WORKDIR` to set path that user have permission to write on container. For example: `/tmp` or `/path/user/have/permission/to/write`